# getting lnk1104 error even when all dependencies removed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

I'm very familiar with solving lnk1104 errors, however this one has me beat.

I've downloaded the quake3 source code from github, compiling in vs2010 pro.

Had to modify the custom build tool that calls masm on the included *.asm files to include parens on visual studio since my paths contain spaces.   Fixed a couple of parameter mismatches.  Now everything compiles ok.

However for last 2 hours I am getting a linker error :

LNK1104: cannot open file '.\Debug\.obj'

It appears that somewhere an empty or misspelled compiler variable is getting inserted into the linker input path, and thus generating this error.  However I can't find anything close to this.   Here's what I've tried to eliminate and/or isolate the issue, with no luck :

1) even though my linker inputs don't contain variable names, to account for something weird i put parens around each input lib in dependencies section... same error.
2) looked at the command line for linker options, don't see anything that could match missing linker input :

/OUT:".\Debug\WinQuake.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO ".\dxsdk\sdk\lib\dxguid.lib" ".\scitech\lib\win32\vc\mgllt.lib" "winmm.lib" "wsock32.lib" "opengl32.lib" "glu32.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:".\Debug\WinQuake.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\Users\Josh Franta\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\qopt\depends\id_quake_source\Quake\WinQuake\Debug\WinQuake.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /PGD:"C:\Users\Josh Franta\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\qopt\depends\id_quake_source\Quake\WinQuake\Debug\WinQuake.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE

3) i've looked at the inherited dependencies, no blank lines or anything other than normal windows libs
4) i've tried disabling default libaries by setting 'ignore all default libraries' to yes.  same error
5) i've tried removing all the 'additional dependencies' inputs.  same error
6) i've searched for all instances of pragma comment, looking for lib or linker directives anywhere in the solution.   nothing found.
7) i've tried turning on verbose linking, don't get any extra output

this has got to be something just absurdly simple.   i'm drawing a blank though.  and missing c# a little bit, grr.

any suggestions appreciated

Comment: Its a target name built from a malformed macro name. I.e. somewhere a single source file has an output file `$(OutDir)$(SomeNondefinedMaybeMistypedMacroName).obj`, which, when expanded, results in `".\Debug\.obj"`. You may have to crank up the verbosity of your build output to know which target is causing this, but I'm pretty sure this is the issue.

Comment: That would make sense although it doesn't appear you can specify single source file output names.  also when i turn off compiler banner suppression to see the initial compilation, all the files are built in once command... here is the compile string : cl /c /I.\scitech\include /I.\dxsdk\sdk\inc /ZI /nologo- /W1 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600 /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /Gy- /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo".\Debug\\" /Fd".\Debug\vc100.pdb" /FR".\Debug\\" /Gd /TC /analyze- /errorReport:prompt [...file list...]

Comment: The /Fo".\Debug\\" does control object files, and that is the path which matches the later link error.  I just can't figure out where it's getting the target name from if it can't be set per file.

Comment: You can specify output file name. Grab any .cpp file, right-click, select properties, drill open the C/C++ tree, select Output Files, on the right side is the "Object File Name" which can be either a directory (in which case the file name is generated from the `$(InputName).obj` in the named directory) or a specific file name. The default setting is a directory, `$(IntDir)`, and thus the default output for any given file will be `$(IntDir)$(InputName).obj` Somewhere I'm guessing either `$(InputName)` has been redefined, or as I said a hard file name from a busted macro is being specified.

Comment: Yeah, ok I get what you're saying.  I had already searched the project file for objectfilename overrides, but there are none at the file level it's all defaults.  Everything looks good even double checked every file from it's individual UI property page. now i'm wondering... the quake source uses masm to generate object files from assembly code for fast parts of quake, so i'm wondering if linker having trouble linking one of the masm generated files.

Comment: That sounds like a definite possibility. If it launches masm via cmdline it may have the target file name to generate mucked up somehow. Btw. I don't envy you. VS build-debugging *sucks*.

Comment: Ok I set visual studio build log to be 'detailed' in the visual studio project options, and I see additional options being passed to linker that I can't see in the linker CLI page.  just can't figure out where it's pulling this from.    link.exe /OUT:".\Debug\WinQuake.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO .\dxsdk\sdk\lib\dxguid.lib .\scitech\lib\win32\vc\mgllt.lib winmm.lib wsock32.lib opengl32.lib glu32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST [...removed options...] /MACHINE:X86 .\Debug\\.obj   <--- this is the problem
         .\Debug\winquake.res
         .\Debug\WinQuake.exe.embed.manifest.res

Comment: masm custom builds actually looks ok in that all of the 'Outputs' for each custom build match the other and dont' see any deformed names.

Comment: so there's some extra file in this list, because it shows up on the call to linker and also to filetracker, and it's always the first file in the list even before the exe and resource files.